# How could I display this?

Tags: java

I'm making a program that allows the user to enter a bet amount, a number between 1-6, and a button that will generate a number between 1-6. If the number the user enters is the as the same number the button generates, then the user will "win" and his current earnings will be displayed. This is what I have so far:

```
private void betTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

}

private void numberGuessTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

}

private void currentWinningsTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

}

private void randomNumberButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    double ranNumber;
    ranNumber = number.nextInt(7-1)+1;
    randomNumberButton.setText(Double.toString(ranNumber));
}

private void enterButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String bet = betTextField.getText();
    String numberGuess = numberGuessTextField.getText();
    Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(bet);
    Double d2 = Double.parseDouble(numberGuess);
    if (d1.equals(d2))
        currentWinningsTextField.setText(Double.toString(d1));
}
```

I'm new to programming, so please bear with me. Thanks!

Comment: `7-1` might be replaced by 6, it will works same, but it will looks nicer

Comment: Why are you using doubles  rather than integers?

Comment: The current winnings will not display.